# Difference in real vs computer simulated probability distribution results.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If this is not the right place to ask this,please guide me. 
I had a thought about what if our basic laws are somehow flawed such that they work in the situations we have observed but not in some other situations. Just the way we once thought of light as a particle but then found about diffraction and interference which were explained only by wave nature, which further failed again and we got the wave-particle duality.

Since we usually use computer simulations for most of the experiments now, how can we ensure that the computer was initially fed the correct laws to work with ?

I had an experiment in mind to compare simulated and real experiment data but I have a doubt in mind. I was about to compare the difference in results of a large number of simulated against real coin tosses. Let's say that I did 100,000 coin tosses and simulated the same number of tosses. If there is a huge difference in the results, would I have proved anything apart from the fact that I had either a biased coin or a flawed program that did not generate numbers **randomly** ?

Comment: Strictly speaking you can't prove anything until you have done "infinitely many" throws; this is a philosophical deficiency of the frequentist model. Practically speaking, you've pretty much proven that one or both of those is the case (where we interpret "biased coin" to include the physical surroundings of the coin; machines that always flip heads exist). But it is not so easy to determine which.

Comment: @Ian That was what I thought but now I have another question in mind. How do we know that a coin is biased ? We surely cannot conclude anything from any results. How do we even know that there are things like a biased coin ?

Comment: The probability model can't really tell us precisely, it can only support beliefs. To get a better justification we should say something about physics; for instance if you weight the heads side more, it will tend to be the bottom more, which will favor flips showing tails.

Comment: @Ian that's a nice explanation. Thanks. But if we have such a biased coin and a similar looking fair coin, can we distinguish between the two experimentally ?